# Javascript stops working when user control is added to the page

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am developing website using asp.net and c#. I have one index page, where the javascript is used for sliding the image. I have created one user control named NewsBar.ascx. In the NewsBar.ascx user control, there is javascript for sliding the news. Both the script runs perfectly. But whenever I import the user control to the index page. The image sliding javascript stops working.

Any idea or solution for this problem?

Index page javasrcipt "Header Part"

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="engine1/style.css" />
<style type="text/css">a#vlb{display:none}</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/wowslider.js"></script>
```

"Body Part"

```
     <div id="wowslider-container1">
        <div class="ws_images">
        <span><img src="1.jpg" alt="" title="" id="wows0"/></span>
        <span><img src="2.jpg" alt="" title="" id="wows1"/></span>
        <span><img src="3.jpg" alt="" title="" id="wows2"/></span>
        </div>
        <div class="ws_bullets"><div>
        <a href="#wows0" title=""><img src="../data1/tooltips/1.jpg" alt="+2Wings"/>1</a>
        <a href="#wows1" title=""><img src="../data1/tooltips/2.jpg" alt="College1"/>2</a>
        <a href="#wows2" title=""><img src="../data1/tooltips/3.jpg" alt="College2"/>3</a>
        </div></div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/script.js"></script>
```

News Bar User Control

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../Resources/Styles/NewsBar/style-newsticker.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script src="../../Resources/Scripts/NewsBar/jquery-1.5.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Resources/Scripts/NewsBar/jcarousellite_1.0.1c4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#newsticker-demo").jCarouselLite({
        vertical: true,
        hoverPause: true,
        btnPrev: ".previous",
        btnNext: ".next",
        visible: 3,
        auto: 3000,
        speed: 500
    });
});
```

I have registered the user control in the web.config and use

```
<uc5:NewsBar runat="server" />
```

to call the user control in the index.aspx page.

Comment: Could be anything, really... use ff or chrome, check your console and please, post some code... otherwise, we'd all be guessing

Comment: some example code would probably be useful

Comment: You can import any .js file that used in user control to index page. Just a guess.

Comment: Perhaps the controls have the same ID or something?

Comment: eh, `#newsticker-demo`? can't see it.

Comment: Check id's of elements and also be sure that js is not overriden

Comment: @michalfranc: Does the differenct verison of the jquery also create the problem. I am using 1.4.2 jquery in index page and 1.5.2 jquery in user control.

Comment: @Krushal Of course that can be a problem. Also reinitializing jquery can be a problem. Try to include jquery script globally in Master page for example.